nestjs lifecycle problem and problem in request
when i send the req to the nestjs server its reseve the req and i sent the image with the req and i resev the image in interceptore and i make another interceprot to resize the image but this interceptor see the req but cant see the req.file
this is interceptor
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class ResizeImageInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
    const req = ctx.getResponse<Request>();
    console.log("Request Body:", req); 
    console.log("Uploaded File:", req.file); 
    return next.handle();
  }
}```

and this controller

```  @Post("/add-brand")
   @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image',{storage: memoryStorage(),}),ResizeImageInterceptor)
   async addBrand(@Body(ValidationPipe) brandInfo: CreateBrand, @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File){

   }```

when i send the req in console print the req and the image appears in req but when i brent the req.file print in console undifiend 

